# How to change the font color in InteliJ Idea Debugger Window？

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts

[image]

It's too dark to See clearly.How to change the font Color???

Comment: have you tried Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | Console Colors?

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't seem to work~